# Вывод значений с массивов в эксель

Tags: php, массивы, excel

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ФИО1
            [1] => ФИО2
            [2] => ФИО3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ФИО4
            [1] => ФИО5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ФИО6
            [1] => ФИО7
            [2] => ФИО8
            [3] => ФИО9
            [4] => ФИО10
        )

)
```

Мне нужно занести каждый подмассив с фамилиями с разделениями между массивами
Что делаю я:

```
for($s = 0; $s < count($data_manager); $s++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data_manager[$s]); $i++) {
        $n = 6 + $i;
        $B = 'C' . $n;
        $string = $data_manager[$s][$i];
        $phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit($B, $string, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае у меня каждый массив просто перезаписывает предыдущий.
Как сделать так, что бы каждое следующее повторение `$i` было `$i + количество предыдущих`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если я вас правильно понял:

```
$i_total = 0;
for($s = 0; $s < count($data_manager); $s++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data_manager[$s]); $i++) {
        $n = 6 + $i_total;
        $B = 'C' . $n;
        $string = $data_manager[$s][$i];
        $phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit($B, $string, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $i_total++;
    }
}
```

Comment: А если в первом цикле for вставить $i_total++; то вообще получиться именно то, что я хотел, а именно разделение между массивами на одну строку. Спасибо!

Comment: @ДмитрийГолобородько Кстати можно удалить `$i_total++;` и изменить строчку с `$n` на `$n = 6 + $i_total++;`